# How to ensure that messages in chat app are displayed immediately to the recipient

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, asp.net-identity

I am working on creating a one-to-one chat application using ASP.NET Core MVC, Identity, and SignalR. However, I'm encountering an issue where, after selecting a user from a list and sending them a message, the message doesn't appear immediately. It only becomes visible after refreshing the browser due to the fact that I have saved it in the database. This is my controller "

```
public class MessagingController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<AppDbContext> _userManager;
        private readonly IHubContext<MessageHub> _hubContext;

        public MessagingController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<AppDbContext> userManager, IHubContext<MessageHub> hubContext)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            var users = _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Id != currentUserId).ToList();
            var messages = _context.Messages
                .Where(m => m.SenderId == currentUserId || m.ReceiverId == currentUserId)
                .Include(m => m.Sender)
                .Include(m => m.Receiver)
                .OrderByDescending(m => m.Timestamp)
                .ToList();
            var viewModel = new IndexViewModel
            {
                Users = users,
                Messages = messages,
                CurrentUserId = currentUserId  // Add this line to pass the current user ID to the view
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }



      
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendMessage(string receiverId, string content)
        {
            var senderId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            var senderName = _userManager.GetUserName(User);

            var message = new Message
            {
                SenderId = senderId,
                ReceiverId = receiverId,
                Content = content,
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now
            };

            _context.Messages.Add(message);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            // Send the message to the sender and the selected user using SignalR
            await _hubContext.Clients.User(senderId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", new { senderName, content, receiverId });
            await _hubContext.Clients.User(receiverId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", new { senderName, content, receiverId });

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }


        public IActionResult LoadMessages(string receiverId)
        {
            var currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            var messages = _context.Messages
                .Where(m => (m.SenderId == currentUserId && m.ReceiverId == receiverId) ||
                            (m.SenderId == receiverId && m.ReceiverId == currentUserId))
                .Include(m => m.Sender)
                .Include(m => m.Receiver)
                .OrderBy(m => m.Timestamp)
                .ToList();

            //return PartialView("_MessageListPartial", messages);
            return PartialView("_ChatPartial", messages);
        }
```

and this my view "

```
@using System.Security.Claims

<!-- Index.cshtml -->
@model IndexViewModel

<div style="display: flex;">

    <!-- Left column: List of Users -->
    <div style="flex: 1; padding-right: 20px;">
        <h1>Users</h1>
        <form asp-action="SendMessage" asp-controller="Messaging" method="post">
            <label>Select a User:</label>

            @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
            {
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="receiverId" value="@user.Id" />
                    @user.UserName
                </label>
                <br />
            }

            <label>Message:</label>
            <input type="text" name="content" />
            <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Right column: Messages -->
    <div style="flex: 2;">
        <h1>Messages</h1>
        <ul id="messagesList">
            @if (Model.Messages.Any())
            {
                @foreach (var message in Model.Messages)
                {
                    <li>
                        @if (message.Sender != null)
                        {
                            <strong>@message.Sender.UserName:</strong>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <strong>Unknown User:</strong>
                        }
                        @message.Content
                    </li>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <p>No messages available.</p>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>


</div>
<script src="~/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script>
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/messageHub")
        .build();

    connection.start().then(function () {
        console.log("SignalR connection established.");
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message) {
        // Handle received message, e.g., update the UI
        console.log("Received message:", message);

        // Get the current user's ID
        const currentUserId = "@User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value";

        // Get the selected receiver's ID from the radio buttons
        const receiverId = document.querySelector('input[name="receiverId"]:checked').value;

        // Check if the message is from the sender and to the selected user
        if (message.senderId === currentUserId && message.receiverId === receiverId) {
            // Append the sent message to the messages list
            const messagesList = document.getElementById("messagesList");
            const listItem = document.createElement("li");
            listItem.innerHTML = `<strong>You:</strong> ${message.content}`;
            messagesList.appendChild(listItem);
        }

        // Check if the message is from the receiver and from the selected user
        if (message.receiverId === currentUserId && message.senderId === receiverId) {
            // Append the received message to the messages list
            const messagesList = document.getElementById("messagesList");
            const listItem = document.createElement("li");
            listItem.innerHTML = `<strong>${message.senderName}:</strong> ${message.content}`;
            messagesList.appendChild(listItem);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After debugging, I saw a live push of the message in the Console window, as follows.

After re-check your code, I found that this line of code should be the root cause.

```
const currentUserId = "@User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value";
```

This Razor syntax should take effect when it is first rendered, after it takes effect it will become html and javascript scripts, and subsequent ReceiveMessage listening events will no longer be able to use it, so we can initialize currentUserId at the beginning, and the modified code is as follows.

[image]

```
@model YourNamespace.IndexViewModel

<div style="display: flex;">
    <!-- Left column: List of Users -->
    <div style="flex: 1; padding-right: 20px;">
        <h1>Users</h1>
        <form asp-action="SendMessage" asp-controller="Messaging" method="post">
            <label>Select a User:</label>
            @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
            {
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="receiverId" value="@user.Id" />
                    @user.UserName
                </label>
                <br />
            }

            <label>Message:</label>
            <input type="text" name="content" />
            <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Right column: Messages -->
    <div style="flex: 2;">
        <h1>Messages</h1>
        <ul id="messagesList">
            @if (Model.Messages.Any())
            {
                @foreach (var message in Model.Messages)
                {
                    <li>
                        @if (message.Sender != null)
                        {
                            <strong>@message.Sender.UserName:</strong>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <strong>Unknown User:</strong>
                        }
                        @message.Content
                    </li>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <p>No messages available.</p>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="~/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script>
    // Global variable for the current user's ID
    const currentUserId = "@User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value";

    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/messageHub")
        .build();

    connection.start().then(function () {
        console.log("SignalR connection established.");
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message) {
        console.log("Received message:", message);

        // Append the message to the messages list
        const messagesList = document.getElementById("messagesList");
        const listItem = document.createElement("li");

        if (message.senderId === currentUserId) {
            listItem.innerHTML = `<strong>You:</strong> ${message.content}`;
        } else {
            listItem.innerHTML = `<strong>${message.senderName}:</strong> ${message.content}`;
        }

        messagesList.appendChild(listItem);
    });
</script>
```